# Combine two almost identical class templates

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17

Below are two mostly identical templates `PgmArray` and `PgmArrayF`. The first one works for lvalue-ref template parameters, the second one work for integral parameters. I like to combine these two into one:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, const T&... Ts>
struct PgmArray final {
    static constexpr uint8_t size = sizeof... (Ts);
    static constexpr T data[] {Ts...};
};

template<typename T, T... Ts>
struct PgmArrayF final {
    static constexpr uint8_t size = sizeof... (Ts);
    static constexpr T data[] {Ts...};
};

struct A{
    uint8_t m = 0;
};

constexpr A a1{1};
constexpr A a2{2};

constexpr auto x1 = PgmArray<A, a1, a2>{}; // ok
constexpr auto x2 = PgmArrayF<int, 1, 2>{}; // ok

//constexpr auto x3 = PgmArrayF<A, a1, a2>{}; // nok
//constexpr auto x4 = PgmArray<int, 1, 2>{}; // nok

int main() {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just reverse what @bolov did and put the manipulation into the parameter pack's type:

```
// separate alias template not strictly necessary, but easier for readability
template<class T>
using maybe_cref = std::conditional_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, T, const T&>;

template <typename T, maybe_cref<T>... Ts>
struct PgmArray final {
    static constexpr uint8_t size = sizeof... (Ts);
    static constexpr T data[] {Ts...};
};
```

Comment: Excellent! Unfortunately this produces ICE with g++ >= 8.0 (g++ 7.1 is fine).

Answer (score 5):

It's not less code, but more maintainable if you change PgmArray often.

```
template<typename T, T... Ts>
struct PgmArray final {
    static constexpr uint8_t size = sizeof... (Ts);
    static constexpr std::decay_t<T> data[] {Ts...};
};

template<typename T>
struct MakePgmArray {
    using TemplateArgument = typename std::conditional_t<
            std::is_integral_v<T>, T, const T&>;
    template<TemplateArgument... Ts>
    using type = PgmArray<TemplateArgument, Ts...>;
};

...

constexpr auto x1 = MakePgmArray<A>::type<a1, a2>{}; // ok
constexpr auto x2 = MakePgmArray<int>::type<1, 2>{}; // ok
```

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by [petersohn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44566877/2805305)

You could also do this:

```
template <typename U, U... Ts>
struct PgmArray final {
    using T = std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<U>>;

    static constexpr uint8_t size = sizeof... (Ts);
    static constexpr T data[] {Ts...};
};

constexpr auto x3 = PgmArray<const A&, a1, a2>{}; // ok
constexpr auto x4 = PgmArray<int, 1, 2>{}; // ok
```

Comment: That was the one I tried first, but I found it cumbersome to write out `PgmArray<const A&, ...>`, that's why I created the `MakePgmArray` struct to decrease noise this way (adding another noise as a side effect, though).

Comment: Ideally one could write a `constexpr` make-helper `make_pgm_array(1, 2, 3)` producing a `PgmArray<int, 1, 2, 3>` but I think, thats impossible without introducing more boilerplate like `std::interger_constant`

Comment: @wimalopaan user defined literals can be of type integer constant.